# leaflet + shiny: "argument is of length zero" in addLegend values

Tags: r, shiny, choropleth, r-leaflet

I'm developing a shiny app to show a choropleth map, using leaflet and a shapefile to add the polygons. Outside shiny everything works fine, but with shiny I got a problem when using `addLegend` as follows:

```
mypal <- reactive({
        colorBin(palette = "RdYlBu", domain = get("map_fires")[[paste0("qm_", selectedYear())]], 
                           bins = 5, reverse = TRUE, pretty = FALSE,
                           na.color = "#FFFAFA")
    })


output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>% 
            addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
            addPolygons(data = map_fires,
                        stroke = TRUE, weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 0.3,
                        fillColor = ~mypal()(get("map_fires")[[paste0("qm_", selectedYear())]]),
                        highlight = highlightOptions(
                            weight = 5,
                            color = "#666",
                            fillOpacity = 0.7,
                            bringToFront = TRUE),
                        label= lapply(stats_labels(), HTML), 
                        labelOptions = labelOptions(
                            style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
                            textsize = "15px",
                            direction = "auto")) %>%
            addLegend(position = "bottomright", pal = ~mypal(), 
                      values = ~get("map_fires")[[paste0("qm_", selectedYear())]], 
                      opacity = 1)
    })
```

The code above returns:

```
Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero
  104: addLegend
...
```

I'm using `paste0("qm_", selectedYear())` to refer to different columns with yearly data.

I believe the problem is in `values = ~get("map_fires")[[paste0("qm_", selectedYear())]]`, but can't tell why. I have already tried to specify the dataset on `addLegend`, and also to put a specific column on `values =` (i.e., without depending on the reactive value of `selectedYear()`), to no avail.

Outside shiny things work good with the code below (where I keep using `get("map_fires")[[paste0("qm_", 2018)]]`, changing `selectedYear()` for a specific year, just to better show my case):

```
mypal <- colorBin(palette = "RdYlBu", domain = get("map_fires")[[paste0("qm_", 2018)]], 
                  bins = 5, reverse = TRUE, pretty = FALSE,
                  na.color = "#FFFAFA")

leaflet() %>% 
    addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
    addPolygons(data = map_fires,
                stroke = TRUE, weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 0.3,
                fillColor = ~mypal(get("map_fires")[[paste0("qm_", 2018)]]),
                highlight = highlightOptions(
                    weight = 5,
                    color = "#666",
                    fillOpacity = 0.7,
                    bringToFront = TRUE),
                label= lapply(stats_labels, HTML), 
                labelOptions = labelOptions(
                    style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
                    textsize = "15px",
                    direction = "auto")) %>%
    addLegend(position = "bottomright", pal = mypal, 
              values = get("map_fires")[[paste0("qm_", 2018)]],
              opacity = 1)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: why use `get("map_fires")` instead of just `map_fires`? What happens if you change it to that? Also, I would look into this line: `fillColor = ~mypal()(get("map_fires")[[paste0("qm_", selectedYear())]]),`

Comment: I was running into another problem without `get`, but now I realize I don't really need it. Anyway, removing it and keeping only `map_fires[[paste0("qm_", selectedYear())]]` didn't change the issue. As for the line `fillColor = ~mypal()(get("map_fires")[[paste0("qm_", selectedYear())]])`, it is not the problem, the app works fine with it if I don't add the legend.

Comment: Without a sample of your data to reproduce the issue, I wouldn't be able to look into it further.

Comment: I've added the code and a data sample here: https://github.com/cassianord/fires_sample

Thank you so much, Phil!

Comment: Within `addLegend()`, what happens if you remove the `~` in the argument `pal = ~mypal()`? i.e. change it to `pal = mypal()`

Comment: It worked! I'm almost sure I have tried to remove the `~` before, but probably I had then other problems too that prevented the code from working. Thank you again, @Phil!